# identify common elements between df rows to create a new column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

My df is shown below.

```
    key       val    
0   A1  [1, 2, 3, 4]
1   A2  [1, 2, 7, 9]    
2   A3  [1, 3, 5]   
3   A4  [6, 9]  
4   A5  [8]
```

I want to create a new column called common which contains which other key has the same value as my current key. The final dataframe would look like:

```
   key        val      common
0   A1  [1, 2, 3, 4]   {'A2':[1, 2], 'A3':[1, 3]} 
1   A2  [1, 2, 7, 9]   {'A1':[1, 2], 'A3':[1], 'A4':[9], 'A5':[7]}
2   A3  [1, 3, 5]      {'A1':[1, 3], 'A2':[1]}
3   A4  [6, 9]         {'A2':[9]}
4   A5  [8]            {}
```

The only way I can think of is to create a column with empty dictionaries and then have two loops to get the result. I wanted to know if there is an easy way to do this. 
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way using `explode` first then `merge`

```
s=df.explode('Val')
s=s.merge(s,on='Val').query('Key_x ! = Key_y').groupby(['Key_x','Key_y']).Val.apply(list)
l=[y.reset_index(level=0,drop=True).to_dict()for x , y in s.groupby(level=0)]
Out[73]: 
[{'A2': [1, 2], 'A3': [1, 3]},
 {'A1': [1, 2], 'A3': [1], 'A4': [9], 'A5': [7]},
 {'A1': [1, 3], 'A2': [1]},
 {'A2': [9]},
 {'A2': [7]}]
df['common']=l
```

Update

```
l={x: y.reset_index(level=0,drop=True).to_dict()for x , y in s.groupby(level=0)}

df['common']=pd.Series(l).reindex(df.Key).values
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer but I get an error saying 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'explode'. Do I need any other dependencies other than pandas to use this?

Comment: It was a pandas version problem.

Comment: *explode* is a quite new function, introduced in version *0.25*. If you have an older version on *Pandas*, upgrade it.

Comment: @WeNYoBen I accidentally had an 8 in in the input dataframe. How would this solution handle it if there were no common values. Thanks

Comment: @Moshee in that case , we may need to do reindex

Answer (score 0):

I assume that each element of *val* column contains a **string**
composed of `[`, a list of numbers (comma separated) and `]`,
just as you could read it from an Excel file.

The first step is to convert *val* column from strings to **sets**
composed of the underlying lists:

```
val2 = df.val.apply(lambda xx: set(eval(xx)))
```

The second step is to compute a *Numpy* square array, with intersection
of these sets (each with each) and "clear" diagonal elements:

```
comm = val2[np.newaxis, :] & val2[:, np.newaxis]
np.fill_diagonal(comm, set())
```

The third step is to create a DataFrame from it, with both *index* and
*columns* taken from *df.key*:

```
ind = df.key.values
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=comm, index=ind, columns=ind)
```

For your sample data, the result is:

```
        A1      A2      A3      A4   A5
A1      {}  {1, 2}  {1, 3}     {1}   {}
A2  {1, 2}      {}     {1}  {1, 9}  {7}
A3  {1, 3}     {1}      {}     {1}   {}
A4     {1}  {1, 9}     {1}      {}   {}
A5      {}     {7}      {}      {}   {}
```

Then define a function, to be applied soon to each row of this table:

```
def commList(row):
    return { k: list(v) for k, v in row.iteritems() if len(v) > 0 }
```

The next step is to apply this function:

```
common = df2.apply(commList, axis=1).rename('common')
```

The result is:

```
A1              {'A2': [1, 2], 'A3': [1, 3], 'A4': [1]}
A2    {'A1': [1, 2], 'A3': [1], 'A4': [1, 9], 'A5': [7]}
A3                 {'A1': [1, 3], 'A2': [1], 'A4': [1]}
A4                 {'A1': [1], 'A2': [1, 9], 'A3': [1]}
A5                                          {'A2': [7]}
Name: common, dtype: object
```

And the final step is to merge *df* and *common* and save it back
into *df*:

```
df = pd.merge(df, common, left_on='key', right_index=True)
```